# Get the PID from a process at first

Tags: python

I have a question about how to get the PID from a process at first, not when the process has finished.

This is because I want to be able to kill the FFmpeg process (not the python script) if necessary, so it doesn't make sense to know its PID at the end.

FYI: This script is getting the PIDs from FFmpeg processes.

Below you will see how I coded this script, which is working fine, but I get the PID at the end, as I mentioned before.

Any idea about how to do it?

```
import json, base64, sys, subprocess

thisList = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
logFileName = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[2]))

p = subprocess.Popen(thisList, stderr = open(logFileName, 'w'))
print(p.pid)
```

As you can see, I am decoding an encoded base64 string (the FFmpeg command line) to protect it because is coming from an URL.

Also, I need to write the FFmpeg output to a file, so I am getting the stderr to write it externally. I encoded its path in base64 too.

Finally to mention that there will be many concurrent FFmpeg PIDs working at the same time, so something like searching the PID using the FFmpeg name is too generic.

It could be possible to launch a second script to search the entire command line of FFmpeg and getting its PID, which could work well in Unix (I already have a script to do that in PHP), but not in Windows. I would like to be compatible in both SO.

That PHP script working in Unix is ...

```
function getPidByCommand($myString)
{
    $pid = 0;
    $myString = str_replace('"', '', $myString);
    exec("ps aux | grep \"${myString}\" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -1", $out);
    if (isset($out[0]))
    {
        $pid = intval($out[0]);
    }
    return $pid;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Mapg

Comment: try import os print('My PID is:', os.getpid()) at the start of the script

Comment: Are you sure? That could get the PID from the python script not from FFmpeg. I want to kill FFmpeg, not the script.

Comment: ah, maybe not, but then i've never tried to just kill ffmpeg on its on because once I've done that, the the script itself becomes useless to me.

Comment: Probably I would need to create a kind of process in the background while I get the PID (or the parent PID) at first. I try to give the freedom to the user to kill FFmpeg if the process is taking longer than expected.

Comment: If you are using UNIX and will kill the subprocess manually, the quick fix can be to run something like: ps aux | grep ffmpeg. Nevertheless, I'm sure there's gotta be something towards the solution in the subprocess documentation.

Comment: read this in another SO question. would "kill "+str(p.pid)" without knowing what it is help?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` doesn't wait for the process to finish, so your code should be doing exactly what you're asking for already.

Comment: Therefore the problem is that I am calling the python script from PHP, and because of that I am receiving the PID when the script has finished.

I have to figure out how to call the script from PHP to get that PID as soon as python print it.

Comment: @Mapg Currently thinking about a way to get it done using asyncio. Hope to update you soon! This will be my [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html)